# Cylinder double integral with no top or bottom

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

this might be an easy question... but im stuck on it, could use some help. Z is already in cylindrical coordinates... so I dont think i need to convert... do I just integrate $r:0...2$, $z:0..2$ ? What about the top and the bottom ?... thats not part of the surface right ?

Let $S$ be the surface of the cylinder of height 2 and radius 2 with the $z$-axis as its axis which has no top or bottom, Evaluate:

$\iint_S(4-z)dS$

thanks in advance for hints/solutions.

Comment: You are being asked to calculate the integral over a surface, not a volume. Can you write down $dS$ in cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: $dS$ = $rd\phi dz$ ?

Comment: That looks correct. How about the limits of integration? Also, notice that $r=2$ is a constant.

Comment: $\phi:0...2\pi$,$z:0..2$. The question is isn't both $z$ and $r$ constant? also... do i subtract the area of the top and bottom ?

Comment: $z$ is not constant because we must integrate the function $4-z$. The top and bottom don't come into play because they are not part of the cylinder. If we were calculating the volume of a soup can, then we would add the top and bottom.

Comment: (thanks user btw, this is helping me understand really well) Ok... but why, when i take the integral are the top and the bottom excluded from the surface ? aren't i taking thin slices of a radius 2 circle up the z axis? or would that be volume ?

Comment: That would be volume. Remember, $r$ is constant. To take the top into consideration, $r$ would have to go from $0$ to $2$. If the $4-z$ wasn't there, this problem would be equivalent to slicing the cylinder along a line parallel to the $z$ axis and laying it flat. You would get $2\pi rz$ as the surface area.

Comment: Right... that makes total sense now! ok.

Comment: I got $24\pi$ as the answer... does that look correct ?

Comment: That's what I got. You are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is easily reduced to a single, 1D integral:

$$2 \pi (2) \int_0^2 dz \, (4-z)$$

This comes from the fact that a surface element here is $dS = 2 \pi (2) dz$.  I trust you can do the integral.